# c++: std::vector of std::vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I need to create a struct that sotres a
`std::vector<std::vector<int>>` that will contain 4 vectors of ints.
I tried the declaration I usually use for vector of vectors:

```
struct myStruct{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector(4);
};
```

but, when I compile, I get this error:

```
myProgram.cpp:79:52: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector(4);
                                           ^
myProgram.cpp:79:52: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

I tried to declare the vector in the struct and then reserve 4 elements in the main(), in the following way:

```
struct myStruct{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector;
};

int main(){
   myStruct s;
   s.myVector.reserve(4);
   s.myVector[0].push_back(1);
   return 0;
}
```

In this way it compiles without errors, but I get a segmentation violation as soon as I try to push_back.

What is the proper way to do this task? And why can't I use the first declaration to specify the size of myVector?
Thank you! :)

Comment: The segmentation fault is because you forgot the difference between `reserve()` and `resize()`. As far as the first declaration goes, try updating your code to the 2011 C++ standard, and use uniform initialization syntax. Get a more recent textbook, if necessary, to learn all about it.

Comment: ^^^^ in case you wonder what that would look like, `std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector{ 4 };` If that doesn't compile you're tool chain needs to be setup to use a later standard language level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default member initializer inside a class or struct must have an `=` token and/or `{`curly braces`}`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector{4};
```

[Note this would be trickier if the type were just `std::vector<int>`, since curly braces for a `vector` imply a sequence of elements. `std::vector<int>{4}` is a vector with size one whose one element is `4`, not a vector of four zeroes. But here it's fine because `{4}` can't convert to `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>`, so that constructor overload isn't eligible, and the `vector(size_type)` constructor does win.]

The example program has undefined behavior because [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) *does not change the size or create any elements*. So `s.myVector[0]` is invalid since the vector is still empty. Remember, `reserve` is just a setup hint for the vector. Any valid program that uses `reserve` would still be valid if you removed all the `reserve` calls.

Using `resize` instead would do what you seem to mean: make the size of `myVector` equal to 4, by creating 4 empty element vectors. Then the `push_back` would add the number 1 to the first of those vectors, resulting in data `{{1}, {}, {}, {}}`.

```
int main(){
   myStruct s;
   s.myVector.resize(4);
   s.myVector[0].push_back(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct myStruct {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector{4};
};

int main() {
    myStruct s;
    s.myVector[0].push_back(1);
    s.myVector[0].push_back(2);
    s.myVector[0].push_back(3);
    s.myVector[0].push_back(4);

    s.myVector[1].push_back(11);
    s.myVector[1].push_back(21);
    s.myVector[1].push_back(31);
    s.myVector[1].push_back(41);

    cout << s.myVector[0][0] << " " << s.myVector[0][1] << " " << s.myVector[0][2] << " " << s.myVector[0][3] << " " << endl;
    cout << s.myVector[1][0] << " " << s.myVector[1][1] << " " << s.myVector[1][2] << " " << s.myVector[1][3] << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> What is the proper way to do this task?

Hope this will answer your question.